# Disable Weekends on ng2-date-picker

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I am looking for a function that can disable weekends on my datepicker. I know that I can use **isDayDisabledCallback** to disable dates but how can I only disable weekends.

```
<dp-date-picker [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" [config]="datePickerConfig"></dp-date-picker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration you can set the callback **isDayDisabledCallback** like that for exclude Saturday and Sunday.

```
config = {
  isDayDisabledCallback: (date) => [0, 6].includes(date.day()) 
};
```